# process.env.ENV_VARIABLE throws undefined value on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, environment-variables

Im trying to call global system variable on windows inside my JavaScript code

[image]

```
        helper.clearAndEnterValue(UsernameInputField, process.env.DEV_USER);
console.log throws undefined
```

however i can call the variable from CMD

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by restarting the intellij, after each time i change the system variable